# About copy construct

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

```
class Wood {
public:
    Wood();
    Wood(const Wood&); //copy constructor
    ~Wood();

private:
    string price;
};

Wood::Wood(const Wood& orig) {
    price(orig.price);   **//error, why?**
}

Wood::Wood(const Wood& orig) : price(orig.price) { //rigth

}
```

If i using the construct initialize and it was correct. But if if using "price(orig.price)" and it will error, why?

Comment: Why do you think it should *not* be an error?

Comment: @AntonSavin, because i think the usage of "price(orig.price)" will use the copy construct function of class std::string.

Answer (score 4):

The function body of a constructor (the part between the opening and closing braces) is no different the body of any other function.  Would you expect this to compile:

```
std::string a, b;
a(b);  // <--- this line?
```

No, of course not. In order for that to compile, `std::string` would need something like an `operator()` overload which takes another string. It doesn't have that.

The code in the initialization list is different. The expressions in an initialization list are not interpreted as normal statements, like those inside a function body. They are interpreted as initializations (e.g. constructor calls). So, in an initialization list, this:

```
: price(orig.price)
```

Is equivalent to a statement like this:

```
std::string price(orig.price);
```

Except that the type of `price` doesn't need to be specified, because that was already done in the class definition.

Note that you cannot do member initialization inside the constructor body, because by the time you get there, all members are already initialized. That's why you need the initialization list. You can, of course, do assignment in the constructor body:

```
price = orig.price;
```

But that is different than initialization. It won't work for some types (such as const members, reference members, or members without default constructors).  And it can be less efficient for some types, since you are constructing first (with the default constructor), and then assigning. But for many types, it doesn't really matter, because a default construction costs practically nothing.

Comment: Thanks, your analyses was very detail and i known the reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's incorrect because price is already constructed. You can't call it's copy constructor if it's already constructed.

You have to do something like price = orig.price;

Answer (score 1):

Examine the compile error and you will see why. In the member initializer list, `price(orig.price)` is [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) of the member variable `price` with the value `orig.price`. In the body of the copy constructor, `price(orig.price)` is a call to an overloaded `operator()` in `std::string` which accepts a `std::string`. Since there is no such overload, you get a compile error.